# find a function that fits this power series

Tags: power-series

I tried to find an expression that fits the power following serie but didn't succeed, it looks almost like the derivative of arcsin, but ...no, it's not:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n(2n)!}{n!}$$

Of course $-1<x<1$
Maybe it's well known, but I didn't find it, neither by integration nor derivation, nor simply searching.
I guess it doesn't exist but I'd like a confirmation.

Comment: This sum diverges for all $x\ne 0$.

Comment: yep, I asked too fast, that's pretty obvious now you tell me.

Answer (score 6):

This is bad.

Let
$$a_n=\frac{x^n(2n)!}{n!}$$
Then
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\frac{x^{n+1}(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{x^n(2n)!}{n!}}$$
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{x(2n+1)(2n+2)}{n+1}$$
and so, no matter what $x$ is (except $x=0$),
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\bigg|=\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg|\frac{x(2n+1)(2n+2)}{n+1}\bigg |=\color{red}{\infty}$$
And so the sum diverges for all nonzero values of $x$.

Comment: Bleh, who needs convergence?

Comment: yeah thanks, I might have been drunk that day. I don't remember why I needed it.

Comment: @kalish If you think this or another answer has answered your question, please click the green $\color{green}\checkmark$ to the side to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Nilknarf shows, the sum diverges, however, it is possible to obtain a [Mittag-Leffler sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_summation).

We will need to require $\Re(x)\le0$ and we get

\begin{align}\mathcal M_2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2n)!}{n!}x^n&=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}x^nt^{2n}\right)~\mathrm dt\\&=\int_0^\infty\exp(xt^2-t)~\mathrm dt\\&=\frac{\pi^{1/2}}{2e^{1/4x}\sqrt{-x}}\left(1-\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac1{2\sqrt{-x}}\right)\right)\end{align}

So I suppose, if it were anything, it'd be that, where $\operatorname{erf}(z)$ is the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Comment: Bugger me I didn't even check the radius and don't remember why I needed that expression, but it is sure it appeared in a physical situation. Thanks all of you for your kind answers.
Edit: now I remember, and it was about integrating a gaussian or something related to a gaussian, so thanks.